# Keep getting ORA-00904: "DISTRICT_ID": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, create-table, insert-into

I keep getting that error message and I have gone through it a bunch of times, I cannot figure out what the best way to fix it is I have tried changing it around a bunch of times.

```
CREATE TABLE dealerships(

dealer_ID number(10)NOT NULL,
location varchar2(20)NOT NULL,
region_ID varchar2(20)NOT NULL,
address number(10)NOT NULL,
street varchar2(20)NOT NULL,
city varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
state varchar2(2) NOT NULL,
zip number(10)NOT NULL,
phone number(10),
sq_ft number(10),
date_opened varchar2 (30),
manager varchar2 (30),
distric_ID number(10),
CONSTRAINT dealershipsID_pk PRIMARY KEY(dealer_ID));

INSERT INTO dealerships(dealer_ID, location, region_ID, address, street, city, state, zip, phone, sq_ft, date_opened, manager, district_ID) VALUES(001, '001', 'RG001', 001, 'STR001', 'Detroit', 'Michigan', 48307, 256897456, 55, '21March2016', 'Tom Petty', 001);

INSERT INTO dealerships(dealer_ID, location, region_ID, address, street, city, state, zip, phone, sq_ft, date_opened, manager, district_ID) VALUES(002, '002', 'RG002', 002, 'STR002', 'Hollywood', 'California', 98290, 2565675309, 85, '1March2011', 'Randy Gilman', 002);
```

Comment: Despite going through it a "bunch of times", you missed the spelling mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously? Look at your code:

```
distric_ID number(10)
```

and

```
district_ID)
```

there is typo.